# Pterodactyl Docker Pulling times out when using iptables

Tags: iptables, docker

When I'm using iptables to block incoming traffic by either:

`- iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT`
or
`- iptables -P INPUT DROP`

It times out and says nothing and just finish pulling. (takes 1 minute).

My current config:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [29875:3958669]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [263459:37321297]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2022 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o pterodactyl0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o pterodactyl0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i pterodactyl0 ! -o pterodactyl0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i pterodactyl0 -o pterodactyl0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i pterodactyl0 ! -o pterodactyl0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o pterodactyl0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1352:194638]
:INPUT ACCEPT [891:120286]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1048:62993]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1048:62993]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o pterodactyl0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i pterodactyl0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

When I left the policy on accept or without rejecting unwanted traffic, docker works significantly faster and doesn't seem to time out:

```
[Pterodactyl Daemon]: Pulling Docker container image, this could take a few minutes to complete...
---this information doesn't show up when I have closed ports---
Pulling from pterodactyl/yolks 
Status: Image is up to date for ghcr.io/pterodactyl/yolks:java_17 
Digest: sha256:2dc464502b22a0c64edbc10a347d9f72b4581640be487b5eb750785d26ccad04 
---this information doesn't show up when I have closed ports---
[Pterodactyl Daemon]: Finished pulling Docker container image
```

So anything I'm doing wrong or something to improve? (I'm new at this I previously used firewalld which worked fine but wasn't good for my needs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im stupid it was simple:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

For already esablished connections to get trough.